# Shield EMF from power cable with aluminium foil

Tags: emf

There is a big electric cable behind a wall.  On the other side, I read around \$2 \mu W / cm^2\$ of EMF at distance about 3 feet from wall.

Is there any way to shield this using aluminium foil?  I tried placing a 1 foot x 1 foot rectangular foil between source and meter, but I got no reduction.

Comment: Is `mu W` standing for \$\mu W\$? Are you sure it's per \$cm^2\$ and not per \$m^2\$ ?

Comment: Yes and yes.  It's $\mu$ and it's $cm^2$ (not $m^2$).  I am measuring with Tenmars TM-195.

Comment: You can use MathJax to format formulas by escaping with `\$`. [More information.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/7195)

Comment: Place a square meter of aluminum foil on the wall, tied to GND (hard to contact AL, because of the instantaneously forming oxide layer). Then remeasure.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain what you mean by "tied to GND (hard to contact AL, because of the instantaneously forming oxide layer)"?

Comment: @Manu Aluminum almost instantly forms a thin, highly insulating sapphire surface on exposure to Earth's high-content oxygen atmosphere. It's thin, so it cracks easily. But it is difficult to get and then maintain good electrical conductivity to aluminum when the surface really just wants to become sapphire.

Comment: Thanks. Repeating the experiment I noticed something: just holding the meter I get a 10x increase in reading, from \$0.2 \mu W/cm^2\$ to 2.  What does this mean?  This happens very prominently near my source.